# Transposing rows from one table based on column values in another table

Tags: sql, ssms

I asked a similar question [here]: [Transposing groups of rows with the same ID into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117689/transposing-groups-of-rows-with-the-same-id-into-another-table)
but I don't want to have to write out each line for each attribute name. I want to be able to take rows in one column from TABLE1 (say there's 50 unique rows) and transpose them efficiently into TABLE2.


This is a small example of a table of ATTR_NMEs (attribute names) in one column:

```
  ID          ATTR_NME          ATTR_VAL
 1000           UPC            00015582981001
 1000          Price              15.99
 1000          Brand               Oreo
 1005           UPC            00038762291010
 1005          Price               12.50
 1005          Brand             Sargento
 1010           UPC            00198872499000
 1010          Price               4.99
 1010          Brand               Olay
```

So ID, UPC, Price, and Brand should be their own columns with the ATTR_VAL as the rows of data. HERE'S THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THIS QUESTION AND MY PREVIOUS ONE: say I have a table with 50 different ATTR_NMEs, I want to use that column of data with all those attribute names to create the new tranposed table without having to write the following 50 times for the different attributes:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN ATTR_NME = 'UPC' THEN ATTR_VAL END) AS UPC
```

I tried to declare a variable for the rows in the ATTR_NME column like this:

```
DECLARE @itm varchar(100);
SET @itm = (
      SELECT ATTR_NME
      FROM TABLE1
      );
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ATTR_NME = @itm THEN ATTR_VAL END) AS [@itm]
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID;
```

But that didn't work for multiple reasons; one being it wanted me to wrap an aggregate function around ATTR_NME where I SET @itm (but then I only got one attribute name). It also didn't label/name the column as I wanted it to. Is it even possible to do what I want to do? If so, how? TIA.

Comment: Dynamic SQL would be the only way this can be done that I know of and only if the columns are consistently named to the attr_name value

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `Pivot`?

If you need to `pivot` this table, you cannot avoid putting the `ATTR_NME` 50 times in the below query (see comment)

```
WITH A
AS
(
 SELECT '1000' as ID,          'UPC  ' as ATTR_NME,          '00015582981001' as ATTR_VAL
 UNION ALL SELECT '1000' as ID,          'Price' as ATTR_NME,          '15.99           ' as ATTR_VAL
 UNION ALL SELECT '1000' as ID,          'Brand' as ATTR_NME,          'Oreo            ' as ATTR_VAL
 UNION ALL SELECT '1005' as ID,          'UPC  ' as ATTR_NME,          '00038762291010' as ATTR_VAL
 UNION ALL SELECT '1005' as ID,          'Price' as ATTR_NME,          '12.50           ' as ATTR_VAL
 UNION ALL SELECT '1005' as ID,          'Brand' as ATTR_NME,          'Sargento        ' as ATTR_VAL
 UNION ALL SELECT '1010' as ID,          'UPC  ' as ATTR_NME,          '00198872499000' as ATTR_VAL
 UNION ALL SELECT '1010' as ID,          'Price' as ATTR_NME,          '4.99            ' as ATTR_VAL
 UNION ALL SELECT '1010' as ID,          'Brand' as ATTR_NME,          'Olay            ' as ATTR_VAL
)
SELECT *
FROM A
PIVOT
  (MAX(ATTR_VAL) FOR ATTR_NME in ([Price],[Brand],[UPC]) ) -- here you need to put all the 50 ATTR_NAME
  as PIVOTTABLE
```

Comment: Perhaps [use dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348), since if it's something like `Price1`, `Price2`, ... , `Price50` you can easily build the column list as a CSV string.